# In Rails form, Bootstrap 3 class is not rendering for select dropdown

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap 3 gem for my Rails app. One good thing about Bootstrap is that it can be used to improve the look of Rails forms through the `.form-control` class.

In one form, I have two inputs: a text_field and a select_field. Based on the [Bootstrap 3 CSS guide](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), I should be able to apply the style using the `.form-control` class:

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div><%= f.label :subdomain %><br />
    <%= f.select :subdomain, ['ExampleOne.com', `ExampleTwo.com`], class: "form-control" %></div>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

In this case, however, the first `text_field` input renders fine as I'd want but the select is unchanged. In a static, non-Rails form, this would be written, according to the documentation, like:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

I don't see a difference in how I am setting this up. Can you spot the error?

Answer (score 1):

Change your select tag to something like below:

```
<%= f.select(:subdomain, ['ExampleOne.com', `ExampleTwo.com`], {}, { :class => 'form-control' }) %>
```

Because it accepts HTML options like `class` in 4th argument here, 3rd argument here is for `options` hash which is used for `options` like `{ include_blank: true }`.

From rails [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) it should be in format of

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Here you already have the `object` since you are applying this on `f` so your `class` should be in 4th argument which is for `html_options`.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you take a step back and code the input field in html, I believe it should work then.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div><%= f.label :subdomain %></div><br />
      <select class="form-control" name="subdomain">
       <%@some_variable.each do |k|%> #instance variable, Directly Model or some array defined in view or controller.
         <option value="<%=k.id%>"><%=k.some_field_name%></option>
       <%end%>          
   </div>
```

If you don't have options from db, you want to hard code it define a array in view or controller and then loop through it.